# Bead on buck regulator circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator, schematics, buck, ferrite-bead

I came across a DC-DC converter schematic and I notice that they use a bead on the schematic. I would like to know the purpose of this chip on this circuit and what the effect of removing it.

[image]

Comment: Notice all those capacitors on the input side to the Switcher? filters need series elements as well as shunt elements. The bead, without adding resistance, provides a series element.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf the capacitors on the input are as follow: 
• 4.7uF capacitors are decoupling capacitors
• 0.22uF is used for high-frequency filtering 
• 47uF after DM filer is electrolytic capacitor that provides damping to the voltage spike
47000 capacitors, I think they are related to bead cause I check the datasheet of LMR IC and I didn’t find any recommendation to include them in the circuit. 
What is the purpose of series elements?

Answer (score 2):

Ferrite beads are typically used to filter out RF noise, in this case most likely noise coming from the SMPS going into the power source.

For lower frequencies, they have L00, but RF has the unfortunate property of considering large coils as arrays of capacitors (think of each winding turn as one side of a plate capacitor) and jump them. So, you often needs an intentionally smaller one to combat that.

Answer (score 0):

1. The purpose of the Bead is to suppress any form of harmonics, specifically it passively suppresses high frequency noise so as to produce stable rhythmic output waveforms.
2. As stated in point one above, removal of the bead could lead to harmonics or too much noise at your output. thus your LMR ic may not function well as it also employs some form of clock or frequency to work properly.